# Developing two android app that can send/trigger notification to each other

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I've been studying android development for about 2 months, and still trying to learn new things and stuffs in mobile dev. And I've been wondering how can two android application send notification to each other. I saw a tutorial about `notificationCompat` wherein a notification pop-up when an action(`onClick`) is performed inside the application. And I thought that maybe it is also possible to trigger that notification from another application. And my question is now, How can I trigger a notification in the 1st application using the 2nd application? And also addtional info will be that the two application is on the same local network(Ad hoc).

Comment: read about Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: can i use this even without the internet connection?

Comment: No you cannot, there is no way 2 devices can send data to each other, other than through wifi or bluetooth, both of which have low range

Comment: I'am using adhoc network, means I am using wifi connection, but no internet, because it is a local network.